# What's the proper tension for the belt on a treadmill?

Tags: running, treadmill

I suspect mine is too loose as it will occasionally slip mid-stride causing my landing to slip forward a bit. Details would be helpful.

Update: If it's relevant, it's a Life Fitness T5-0 treadmill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to adjust some unidentified, unknown treadmill.

Comment: @JohnP I wish you had just requested that I append the additional information instead of voting to close. I added it to the body of the question. I had excluded it because I was envisioning a similar answer regardless of make or model.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of treadmill it is, the question is off topic. Gear used during exercise is on topic if you are asking about it as part of an exercise program, not how to repair it.

Comment: @JohnP Understood. Do you have a suggestion for where it would be more appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is an exchange site that would work for this. You should be able to go to the manufacturers website and download the instructions/troubleshooting, or they may have support forums available.

Comment: -1 Definity off topic, hard to vote down generally but here it is, done deed, good or bad

Answer (score 3):

Start by turning on the machine and pressing “Start.”  Adjust the speed to the lowest setting. Let the belt rotate a few times. If the running belt starts to shift toward one side, loosen the rear roller bolt on the opposite side ¼ turn clockwise. For example, if the running belt begins to shift to the left, loosen (turn counter clockwise) the right roller bolt a ¼ of a turn. The key to this is patience as you must wait five revolutions of the running belt between each adjustment. That will ensure you do not over correct the belt.

If you need more information read here:
http://www.visionfitness.com/blog/how-to-align-and-tension-your-treadmill-running-belt/